# Call class method of default import in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm wondering whether its possible to call a method on a component that I import from another file. Basically, my situation is that I have two react classes. One of them is a Sudoku puzzle, which I call Game, and which includes the updateArray() method:

```
class Game extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {arr: [[5,0,4,9,0,0,0,0,2],
                          [9,0,0,0,0,2,8,0,0],
                          [0,0,6,7,0,0,0,0,9],
                          [0,0,5,0,0,6,0,0,3],
                          [3,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,1],
                          [4,0,0,1,0,0,9,0,0],
                          [2,0,0,0,0,9,7,0,0],
                          [0,0,8,4,0,0,0,0,6],
                          [6,0,0,0,0,3,4,0,8]]};

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.updateArray = this.updateArray.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(nextProps.arr != this.props.arr){
            this.setState({arr: nextProps.value });
        }  
    }

    updateArray(str_arr) {
        this.setState({arr: str_arr});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {

        ...

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className = "game">
                    <div className = "game-board">
                        <Board value = {this.state.arr} />
                    </div>
                    <div className = "game-info">
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Game;
```

And then I have a second class that gets a image of a sudoku puzzle and makes a corresponding 9x9 array using computer vision methods. I then try to send the array back to Game using its updateArray function:

```
import Game from './Sudoku';


export default class ImageInput extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
             uploadedFile: ''
        };

    }

    onImageDrop(files) {
        this.setState({uploadedFile: files[0]});
        this.handleImageUpload(files[0]);
    }

    handleImageUpload(file) {
        var upload = request.post('/')
                            .field('file', file)

        upload.end((err, response) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(Game);
                //ERROR HAPPENING HERE 
                Game.updateArray(response.text);

            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <Dropzone
                multiple = {false}
                accept = "image/jpg, image/png"
                onDrop={this.onImageDrop.bind(this)}>
            <p>Drop an image or click to select file to upload</p>
            </Dropzone>
        );
    }
}
```

However, when I try to send the array to Game's method, I get a Uncaught TypeError:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _Sudoku2.default.updateArray is not a function
    at eval (image_input.js?8ad4:43)
    at Request.callback (client.js?8e7e:609)
    at Request.eval (client.js?8e7e:436)
    at Request.Emitter.emit (index.js?5abe:133)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (client.js?8e7e:703)
```

I want the updateArray() method to update the Game from a separate file, which will then cause the Game to re-render. Is this possible? I've spent a lot of time reading documentation, and it seems as though what I'm suggesting is not the typical workflow of react. Is it dangerous, and if so, can someone explain why?

Also, both classes are rendered in a separate file that looks like this:

```
import Game from './Sudoku';
import ImageUpload from './image_input';


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(ImageUpload),
        document.getElementById('image-upload'),
    );
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(Game),
        document.getElementById('sudoku_game'),
    );
});
```

Comment: have your updateArray method in the second class and send the updated array as props to the first class

Comment: @Prasanna is right. How and when is your Game component being rendered? It's not clear from the code you posted only.

Comment: Well `Game` is a class. It's `updateArray` method is on a specific instance. *Which* game do you want to re-render - there might be multiple components?

Comment: @BrunnoVodolaMartins I edited my question to show how they are rendered. Sending the array is props to the first class seems to me like its creating a new instance of Game, rather than updating the value of state.arr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in your separate file (the one rendering both `Game` and `ImageInput` components):

Make it render only one component. This could have a original name like `App` for instance. Like this:

```
import App from './App';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(App),
        document.getElementById('root'),
    );
});
```

You would only have to change the imports and name of the root element as needed of course.

---

Then, for the App component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Game from './Sudoku';
import ImageUpload from './image_input';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      sudokuArray = [];  
    }
  }

  updateArray(newArray) {
    this.setState({sudokuArray: newArray})
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <Game sudokuArray={this.state.sudokuArray} />
      <ImageUpload  updateArray={this.updateArray.bind(this)} />
    </div>
  }
}

export default App;
```

---

And inside your `ImageInput` component you would call the update method like: 
`this.props.updateArray(response.text)`.

---

Also, inside your `Game` component, change the render function, specifically the part with the Board component to: `<Board value = {this.props.sudokuArray} />`.

---

This is a rather common situation when you are learning React. You find yourself trying to pass some prop or run some method inside a component that is not "below" the component you are currently working with. In these cases, maybe the prop you want to pass or the method you want to run should belong to a parent component. Which is what I suggested with my answer. You could also make `Game` as a child of `ImageInput` or vice-versa.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and the flow of information is beginning to make a lot more sense to me know. Thanks!